# I made changes on my server and now git won't let me push to master because it has "unstaged changes." How can I get around this?

Tags: git

Noob question about Git:

I made a few minor changes on my server directly (without using Git). I just opened cPanel and changed the names of a few image files and deleted a few unused images.

Then I went back to my code editor and made changes in a few files. But I can't push to master now, because Git says, "! [remote rejected] master -> master (Working directory has unstaged changes)"

I'm not sure how to get around this. I wouldn't mind a solution that undoes the changes I made directly to the server files. I wouldn't mind a solution that loses the changes I made to my text in the editor either. They were all very minor. I just want them back in sync!

I tried to create a new branch with "git checkout -b example" and did "git pull" into that branch. That went fine. I can push too, and I can "git checkout master" and then "git merge example" and that seems successful. But then when I "git checkout master" and then "git push origin master" it gives me the error message.

I appreciate any advice you can give!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple solution for your case is to:

1. enter your server's repo directory
2. `rm -r *`        (Warning: This will delete everything)
3. `git reset --hard` (Best Working)
   or `git checkout -- .`

Having step 2 is just in case your future changes have files in conflict.

Step 3 resets every tracked files on your working directory back to the current branch's version.

---

If you would like to keep the changes, you can perform `git add .` and then `git commit` on your server, and then on your machine do `git pull`, which should trigger a *merge*. Then you can push as usual.

Comment: This was perfect! Actually, "git checkout --" didn't do the trick. It just erased the whole directory on my server except for my .git folder, and I still couldn't "git push origin master" but once I used "git reset --hard" it finally let me push and now all is great! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

To clear the recent changes and go back to the last state (last commit), just make sure you're at the top-level of your repo, and do

```
git checkout -- .
```

Another way to clear these changes is `git stash` which would put these changes in an isolated branch, just in case you regret having wiped them earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes file changes could be file permissions.
You can check which with.

git add -p .